# Optimal Drill Placement for Tunneling w/Rovers

Tags: space-engineers

Trying my hand at rover design, and the current challenge is to build a compact rover that can easily drill directional tunnels between ore deposits (I have a cluster of five within 500m of each other).  Eventually I will add articulation to handle turning, descending, and ascending, but for right now I'm trying to build a rover that will drill at the same grade the wheels are sitting on.  For the life of me, I can't seem to find the right placement, however.

What is the maximum volume of effect for a small grid drill (and large grid while we're at it) and how far from the centerline of the drill (base to tip, from where the block defaults to being placed) in all directions does it extend?

Answer (score 1):

Small grid drill blocks have an area of effect larger than their block size; whereas large grid drill blocks have an area of effect roughly equal to their block size.

The problem is that the small grid drill's AOE is spherical rather than cubic. And the diameter is not equal to an exact number of small armor blocks. Thus, you won't be able to position the drills such that the bottom pole of the sphere will exactly line up with the base of your wheels.

To solve this, you can attach your drill assembly to a hinge or piston to achieve more micro adjustments to the drills' angle or height of attack.

One thing to be aware of with this approach: If you use hinges or pistons (or rotors for that matter), you're effectively relegating your drills to a subgrid. In fact, anything on the other side of the hinge or piston will be on a subgrid. And this has two potential consequences:

1. You won't be able to effectively blueprint your vehicle in survival mode. Projectors cannot project subgrids in survival. If you're in creative this is a nonissue.
2. Each subgrid has their own center of mass, and so your drill assembly will have a center of mass distinct from your vehicle's main body. This may cause your vehicle to be off balance and bounce or rock as you drill especially as your drills' internal containers fill. As a result, you may see irregular terrain modification (like small ridges) as you drive and your vehicle bounces slightly due to multiple centers of mass being calculated against acceleration/deceleration and friction.

Comment: I always wondered what those ridges were about! Thank you for this.  Are wheel suspension heights of sufficient range that they can simulate the piston effect? And if so, do you happen to know what offsets for 3x3 and 5x5? (1x1 wheels seem mostly for comedy.)

Comment: Offsetting the wheel height could work. That's a good idea. I haven't tried it so I don't know what height you'd need to offset by. Worth experimentation for sure though. Just remember to give your suspensions enough strength to hold the offset even when the drills and your containers fill up.

Comment: Yeah, I just need to figure out how far below the collision box of the drill, the excavation effect goes and then I can measure it down.